They sing "One of Us" to the new guy
There is a movie where this couple (boy and girl, adolescents, around 25 yo) sing the chant One of Us citing the popular movie Freaks. They are lovers, but they want this new guy to join them in a sort of a threesome.
I remember that the moment they sing they are in a bathtub, this guy is blonde, is quite shy at the beginning, I feel like it was Di Caprio, but maybe it confuses me the fact that he also cited freaks in The Wolf of Wall Street.
I'd like to remember which movie it is, I think it is also quite popular, from the 90's.

Please the people who downvote, write some comments so that we new users can learn from you.

This sounds like The Dreamers (2003), with Michael Pitt (who's blonde and kind of looks like Di Caprio) and Eva Green. 

the film tells the story of an American university student in Paris who, after meeting a peculiar brother and sister who are fellow film enthusiasts, becomes entangled in an erotic conflict.

The 'one of us' quote is mentioned here

Isabelle, Theo: We accept you, one of us! One of us!

Dreamers is also cited on the Wikipedia page for Freaks itself:

The chant, along with a corresponding clip from the movie, is used in The Dreamers, directed by Bernardo Bertolucci.


Yes it is! I wouldn't even need to double check after reading the title but I'll watch it again indeed. It was really naive not using Wikipedia citations section. Thank you @tibs!
And they were brother. I remember that, but I didn't put it on the question because it sounded too weird at first.
